# Node API and Angular App - Understanding Storing JWTs in Cookies

Tags: angularjs, node.js, cookies, xss, csrf-protection

I've built an API with Node.js/Express which I'm currently using alongside my Angular app.

For authentication, I have a username/password setup which then returns a JWT which is happily used.

Now, I've been spending some time (and reading [such Stormpath articles](https://stormpath.com/blog/where-to-store-your-jwts-cookies-vs-html5-web-storage/)) I want to use cookies rather than localstorage for storing these JWTs. And thats where my questions begin.

So what I've essentially done thus far is updated the saving and reading, e.g. for saving from `$window.localStorage['jwtToken'] = token;` to `$cookies.put('jwtToken', token);`. And for reading, from `return $window.localStorage['jwtToken'];` to `return $cookies.get('jwtToken');`

At this stage I was wondering whether someone could help me understand a few bits, kindly correct and inform me of any missing parts of knowledge:

1 - So in addition to the actual saving and reading as above, is there anything else I need to explicitly set - what I think is `HttpOnly` cookie flag (so JS can't access the cookie data.

1b - Do i also need to update my node API so that instead of returning `res.json` its doing `res.cookie`?

2 - Do i also need to set the `Secure` cookie flag so that its sent via HTTPs. So at present i wrote a simple authInterceptor that attaches a header with each request: `config.headers['x-access-token'] = token;`. Is this where that `secure` cookie flag would be set?

3 - So using cookies am i correct to understand XSS attacks are minimised as JS can't touch the cookies however I need to concentrate on CSRF. For this I am thinking of using this [CSRF middleware](https://www.npmjs.com/package/csurf) on my node api server side and use this alongside Angulars built in XSRF-TOKEN as described [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#cross-site-request-forgery-xsrf-protection). Is this a good implementation to follow?

4 - When looking at Chrome inspector, I see the cookie containing the JWT, however the HTTP/Secure/Same-Site are all untucked, also the Expires says Session. Could someone please explain what this means:
[image]

Sigh, I think thats it, sorry if its a little long winded. Hopefully others can gain from what we learn here.

Any help appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

1. If you set HttpOnly `$cookies.get('jwtToken');` wouldn't work...
   1b. Don't understand the question here...
2. The Secure flag tells the browser to only include the cookie if the request is an HTTPS request. You can still make HTTP requests, but the cookie will not be included. `document.cookie = "name=somevalue;secure"`
3. If you set HttpOnly so that JavaScript can't read the cookie, that's some protection, but if you have XSS, then all bets are off. The injected script could still perform network requests, and do exactly what your code is doing to include the CSRF tokens. You still need CSRF-protection, but in most cases XSS means circumvention of CSRF-protection.
4. Session means the cookie will be deleted automatically if you close the browser (which people don't really do all that often anymore).

Comment: Thanks - so in question 1b what i meant to say my API returns JSON (I'm using express's `res.json()` so my first change I presume needs to be at the backend so that its actually returns a cookie?
Also will this mean every response now needs to be a cookie? e.g. even if i were sending basic, public viewable data?

Comment: Yeah, you could change it to set the cookie instead of setting it from JS. Remember the secure flag.

Comment: You say 'could change it to set a cookie'  - is there a big secuirty risk I avoid if i dont?
I'm just understanding now, how saving it in a cookie will all of sudden make it more secure. If you know of any pages I should read would appreciated any guidance. Cheers